# Creating AngularDart component that can display it's inner HTML

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have been trying to create a component for illustrative purposes that could display it's own inner HTML markup before it was processed by AngularDart itself, e.g. if I write

```html
<view-source>
  <h1 ng-if="foo == 1">{{bar}}</h1>
</view-source>
```

I want to have actual markup displayed under the normally rendered `h1`. I tried the following code:

```dart
@NgComponent(
    selector: 'view-source',
    templateUrl: 'view-source.html',
    publishAs: 'self'
)
class ViewSource {
  var template;
  ViewSource(dom.Element element) : template = element.innerHtml;
}
```

```html
<!-- view-source.html -->
<div>
  <div class="rendered">
    <content></content>
  </div>
  <div class="template">
    {{self.template}}
  </div>
</div>
```

This works for simple cases but it does not work if something inside `<view-source>` is compiled via transclusion, so instead of `h1` with `ng-if` it will show `<!-- ANCHOR:... -->`.

I tried to find a solution by reading AngularDart source, but I could find any, so I ended up patching AngularDart to attach template clone to each anchor it inserts, so that later I can extract it and splice back in. You can see a [demo](http://mrale.ph/talks/ngdart/#/26) of that.

I wonder if there is a clean solution without patching AngularDart.

Comment: I was able to use your example as it for a simple text only innerhtml fetch.

Comment: @curt yeah it works for simple stuff, does not work for complicated things. I have not revisited this issue since. Maybe in Angular2 there is a clear solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used the `ng-non-bindable` directive to achive this.

[AngularDart UI](http://akserg.github.io/angular.dart.ui.demo/build/index.html)
(looks somewhat broken because the tab control is still missing)

The code https://github.com/akserg/angular.dart.ui.demo/search?q=ng-non-bindable&ref=cmdform

I load the HTML template file using an HTTP request, insert it using `ng-bind` and prevent Angular from processing it using `ng-non-bindable`